# How to see "Network Security Address Group" details

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We created an [address group](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/address-groups-firewall-policies#organization-scoped-address-group) at the organization level using the following command:

```bash
# create address group
gcloud network-security org-address-groups create trusted-ips \
   --organization my-organization \
   --type IPv4 \
   --capacity 100 \
   --location global \
   --description List of trusted IPs

# add IPs to the address group
gcloud network-security org-address-groups add-items trusted-ips \
    --organization my-organization \
    --items 1.2.3.4 \
    --location global
```

The commands finished successfully. Then, we used this address group in the firewall policy rule, which is also visible on the GUI:

[image]

Is there an option to see the details of `trusted-ips` (list of IP addresses) somewhere on the GUI? There exists a CLI command (`gcloud network-security org-address-groups list`), but we are intererested in being able to see it in the web console.

Answer (score 1):

Upon checking the documentation, since the only option to view the list is indicated in "gcloud” only, meaning that is the only option that the GCP have for this particular command. You can see in my screenshot below that the command can only perform in "gcloud” and there are no other options beside it.

One way to compare this concern is the configuration of other features in GCP documentation. Below is a screenshot of configuring a firewall rule for health check wherein you can see that there are other options aside from "gcloud”. There is an option for "console” and also for "terraform”

If an option for another platform like "console” is not visible from the configuration I believe that is already an indication that there are no other options to check the dedicated feature. However, this is worth filing as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).[image][image]

Comment: I created a public issue on their issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/317084203